# Gnome keyboard shortcut not executing command

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, window-management

I have a one-liner which brings a given window to the front. In this case, IntelliJ:

`xdotool windowactivate $(wmctrl -lx | grep jetbrains | awk '{ print $1 }')`

This works as expected when run via a terminal. However, when I set it as a custom keyboard shortcut in Gnome under Super + T, nothing happens.

Why is it not working as a keyboard shortcut?